# Find minimum and maximum in records separated by strings in awk

Tags: awk

With a file like this:

```
line0   200     1500
line1   750     1000
line2   600     1700
line3   150     1100
line4   400     1800
line5   100     1900
line6   950     1200
line7   250     1400
```

...I find the minimum value in the second column and the maximum value in the third column with this script:
`awk '{if(min==""){min=$2;max=$3};if($3>max){max=$3};if($2< min){min=$2}} END {print min,max}' file`

I will appreciate help in doing the same thing but now for each group of lines separated by "YYYY" and "XXXX" in the same file as in the following:

```
YYYY
line0   200     1500
line1   750     1000
line2   600     1700
line3   150     1100
line4   400     1800
line5   100     1900
XXXX
YYYY
line6   950     1200
line7   250     1400
line8   200     2500
line9   350     2000
XXXX
YYYY
line10  500     2700
line11   50     2100
line12  300     2800
line13  700     2900
line14  400     2200
line15  300     2400
XXXX
```

The desired output would be:

```
100 1900
200 2500
50  2900
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/XXXX/{print min, max;min=max=""} 
     min==""||$2<min{min=$2} 
     max==""||$3>max{max=$3}' file   

100 1900
200 2500
50 2900
```

Instead of the END block print the results after the block.  If you know the range of the numbers you can assign out of range values for max and min for reset or more generally empty string as above.